# How can i compute the average percentage increase of the population of this list from year to year?

Tags: python, list, tuples

MIDYEAR_POPULATION = [(1971, 21962032), (1972, 22218463), (1973, 22491777), (1974, 22807969), (1975, 23143275), 
                      (1976, 23449808), (1977, 23725843), (1978, 23963203), (1979, 24201544), (1980, 24515667),
                      (1981, 24819915), (1982, 25116942), (1983, 25366451), (1984, 25607053), (1985, 25842116),
                      (1986, 26100278), (1987, 26446601), (1988, 26791747), (1989, 27276781), (1990, 27691138),
                      (1991, 28037420), (1992, 28371264), (1993, 28684764), (1994, 29000663), (1995, 29302311),
                      (1996, 29610218), (1997, 29905948), (1998, 30155173), (1999, 30401286), (2000, 30685730),
                      (2001, 31020596), (2002, 31358418), (2003, 31641630), (2004, 31938004), (2005, 32242364),
                      (2006, 32570505), (2007, 32887928), (2008, 33245773), (2009, 33628571), (2010, 34005274), 
                      (2011, 34342780), (2012, 34750545), (2013, 35152370), (2014, 35535348), (2015, 35832513), 
                      (2016, 36264604), (2017, 36708083), (2018, 37057765), (2019, 37589262)]

```
def average_percentage_increase(pop_stats):
```

In this function I want it to find the percentage difference from each year to year, and then return the average percentage change.

Comment: Please be more specific. Is this a mathematics/statistics question, or a Python programming one?

Comment: robertanhorn, If you calculated a result already for this hardcoded list of tuples, please indicate the non-rounded result and indicate if it matches the results presented by the authors who submitted code to answer your question.

Comment: Other solutions have already been presented so I'll just note the algorithm must not calculate delta between 1971 and previous year (which does not exist in universe of this data).  Further, it should not add that delta to the sum of the individual delta percentages.  Finally, it should not simply divide that accumulated sum by the number of years in the list of tuples - instead divide by one less than the number of years.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each one

```py
from statistics import mean

MIDYEAR_POPULATION = [(1971, 21962032), (1972, 22218463), (1973, 22491777), (1974, 22807969), (1975, 23143275), (1976, 23449808), (1977, 23725843), (1978, 23963203), (1979, 24201544), (1980, 24515667), (1981, 24819915), (1982, 25116942), (1983, 25366451), (1984, 25607053), (1985, 25842116), (1986, 26100278), (1987, 26446601), (1988, 26791747), (1989, 27276781), (1990, 27691138), (1991, 28037420), (1992, 28371264), (1993, 28684764), (1994, 29000663), (1995, 29302311), (1996, 29610218), (1997, 29905948), (1998, 30155173), (1999, 30401286), (2000, 30685730), (2001, 31020596), (2002, 31358418), (2003, 31641630), (2004, 31938004), (2005, 32242364), (2006, 32570505), (2007, 32887928), (2008, 33245773), (2009, 33628571), (2010, 34005274), (2011, 34342780), (2012, 34750545), (2013, 35152370), (2014, 35535348), (2015, 35832513), (2016, 36264604), (2017, 36708083), (2018, 37057765), (2019, 37589262)]
diff = [
    (f'{prev_year}-{next_year}', next_year_population*100/prev_year_population)
    for (prev_year, prev_year_population), (next_year, next_year_population) in zip(MIDYEAR_POPULATION[0:-1], MIDYEAR_POPULATION[1::]) 
]

print(diff)
>>> [('1971-1972', 101.16761053804129), ('1972-1973', 101.23012109343478), ... ('2018-2019', 101.43423922084885)]

avg = mean(value for y,value in diff)
print(avg)
>>> 101.12606694880344
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that you can do this:

```
percentageIncreases = []
result = 0
for x in range(1, len(MIDYEAR_POPULATION)):
    year, pop = MIDYEAR_POPULATION[x]
    lastYear, lastPop = MIDYEAR_POPULATION[x - 1]
    percentageIncreases.append(pop / lastPop * 100)

result = sum(percentageIncreases) / len(percentageIncreases)
```

Or, using list comprehension:

```
percentageIncreases = [MIDYEAR_POPULATION[x][1] / MIDYEAR_POPULATION[x - 1][1] * 100 for x in range(1, len(MIDYEAR_POPULATION))]
result = sum(percentageIncreases) / len(percentageIncreases)
```

**NOTE:** If you want, you could add the `round` function to the end so the decimal places aren't that long.

Example:

```
result = round(sum(percentageIncreases) / len(percentageIncreases), 2) # Rounds result to two decimal places
```

**NOTE 2:** If you want, you could also use the `mean` function from `statistics` to make the code a bit smaller:

```
from statistics import mean
result = mean([MIDYEAR_POPULATION[x][1] / MIDYEAR_POPULATION[x - 1][1] * 100 for x in range(1, len(MIDYEAR_POPULATION))])
```

Comment: Ayush Garg, Please indicate the non-rounded result you arrived at programmatically.  Does it match the result Marcos' presented?

Answer (score 0):

Your function would look something like this:

```
MIDYEAR_POPULATION = [(1971, 21962032), (1972, 22218463), (1973, 22491777), (1974, 22807969), (1975, 23143275), (1976, 23449808), (1977, 23725843), (1978, 23963203), (1979, 24201544), (1980, 24515667), (1981, 24819915), (1982, 25116942), (1983, 25366451), (1984, 25607053), (1985, 25842116), (1986, 26100278), (1987, 26446601), (1988, 26791747), (1989, 27276781), (1990, 27691138), (1991, 28037420), (1992, 28371264), (1993, 28684764), (1994, 29000663), (1995, 29302311), (1996, 29610218), (1997, 29905948), (1998, 30155173), (1999, 30401286), (2000, 30685730), (2001, 31020596), (2002, 31358418), (2003, 31641630), (2004, 31938004), (2005, 32242364), (2006, 32570505), (2007, 32887928), (2008, 33245773), (2009, 33628571), (2010, 34005274), (2011, 34342780), (2012, 34750545), (2013, 35152370), (2014, 35535348), (2015, 35832513), (2016, 36264604), (2017, 36708083), (2018, 37057765), (2019, 37589262)]


def average_percentage_increase(pop_stats):
    all_differences = list()
    for i, year in enumerate(pop_stats):
        if i > 0:
            difference_in_percentage = year[1] / pop_stats[i - 1][1]
            all_differences.append(difference_in_percentage)

    return sum(all_differences) / len(all_differences)

factor = average_percentage_increase(MIDYEAR_POPULATION)
percentage = (factor - 1) * 100
percentage_rounded = round(percentage, 2)
print(factor)
print(percentage)
print(percentage_rounded)
```

Where with your data I would get the following results:

```
factor: 1.0112606694880342
percentage: 1.126066948803417
percentage_rounded: 1.13
```

Hope this helps, and for future questions, please show what you have already tried and what the expected answer would be so that the people who try to help you can validate their response.

Comment: Timo Frionnet, Please indicate the non-rounded result you arrived at programmatically.  Does it match the result Marcos' presented?